# Qt 5.5 project build error in Qt 5.8

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I was developing a simple application on Qt 5.5. Since Qt 5.5 does not have [QChart](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html) class features, I had to install and build my Qt 5.5 project on the 5.8 distribution. For my project I am using this 3rd party software called the [QXlsx](http://qtxlsx.debao.me) to create and edit Excel spreadsheets. This library was working flawlessly in Qt 5.5 but fails to compile on the Qt 5.8 version. The compilation returns the following error;

> `/Users/Vino/Documents/My Stuff/Qt Projects/Fundemental Analysis/FundementalAnalysis/3rdparty/qtxlsx/src/xlsx/xlsxzipreader.cpp:52: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'QVector<QZipReader::FileInfo>'
>       QList<QZipReader::FileInfo> allFiles = m_reader->fileInfoList();
>                                                        ^`
>   I am not sure what it means, but I am quite confident that I don't have to make any changes on the source code of this library since it worked previously on Qt 5.5.

Anyway this is the source code where the error occurs

```
#include "xlsxzipreader_p.h"
#include <private/qzipreader_p.h>



namespace QXlsx {

    ZipReader::ZipReader(const QString &filePath) :
    m_reader(new QZipReader(filePath))
    {
         init();
    }

    ZipReader::ZipReader(QIODevice *device) :
    m_reader(new QZipReader(device))
    {
         init();
    }

    ZipReader::~ZipReader()
    {

    }

    void ZipReader::init()
    {
           QList<QZipReader::FileInfo> allFiles = m_reader->fileInfoList();
           foreach (const QZipReader::FileInfo &fi, allFiles) {
           if (fi.isFile)
                 m_filePaths.append(fi.filePath);
    }
}

     bool ZipReader::exists() const
     {
           return m_reader->exists();
     }

    QStringList ZipReader::filePaths() const
    {
       return m_filePaths;
    }

    QByteArray ZipReader::fileData(const QString &fileName) const
    {
         return m_reader->fileData(fileName);
    }
}// namespace Xlsx
```

The error occurs at this function;

```
    void ZipReader::init()
    {
         QList<QZipReader::FileInfo> allFiles = m_reader->fileInfoList();
         foreach (const QZipReader::FileInfo &fi, allFiles) 
         {
              if (fi.isFile)
              m_filePaths.append(fi.filePath);
         }
    }
```

***So as a solution I tried adding*** `#include <QList>` ***to the source code since*** `QList` ***is referenced with specifying the header but this does not resolve the issue***. ***When I added*** `#include <QList>`, ***a new myriad of errors popped up. How can I build this project?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem; I was using the oldest version of the QXlsx, and according to this [post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/73153/qt-xlsx-problem-in-compile-the-project/2), there were many new revisions on gitHub. Installing the new version solved the issue.

[New version](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter/tree/master/src/xlsx)
[Old version](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter/tree/master/src/xlsx)

Answer (score 2):

the error for QtXLSX has not been solved.

The solution is simple.

On the file xlsxzipreader.cpp, it is necesary to include:

```
#include <QVector>
```

After that in the function: void ZipReader::init(){}, we need to update the type:

```
void ZipReader::init(){
// This was the previous definition
//QList<QZipReader::FileInfo> allFiles = m_reader->fileInfoList();

QVector<QZipReader::FileInfo> allFiles = m_reader->fileInfoList();

foreach (const QZipReader::FileInfo &fi, allFiles) {
    if (fi.isFile)
        m_filePaths.append(fi.filePath);
    }
}
```

Just save and do again:

```
make
make install
```

This has been tested on Qt 5.8.x, 5.9.x

Cheers!